# Add 'get latest version' to right click menu visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, source-control-explorer

I was hoping to modify the right click context menu on Visual Studio 2015 (professional) so that when I right click in Team Explorer, I don't have to navigate through 'advanced' to get to 'get specific version'.
It's more of a convenience than anything, but it would be greatly appreciated if someone knew how to set that up.
Is there possibly a plugin or a setting deep within the options screen that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

My coworker found an easy way to modify all context menus, this set up gives the solution I was looking for:

1. [Tools]>[Customize...]>[Commands]
2. select the [Context menu] radio button
3. select [Team Foundation Context Menus | Source Control Explorer]
4. click [Add Command...]
5. curse the person who did not include a search feature on the Add Command dialogue box
6. select [File] from the [Categories] list
7. select [TfsGetSpecificVersion] from the [Commands] list